# Python is skipping if condition even though true

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm learning from LPTHW and basically it's a text based game on rooms.

```
class Riddle_Room(Room):
    def activate(self):
        global current_room
        print "Riddle room query"
        current_room = "riddle_room"
        self.ip = raw_input("> ")
        self.count = 3
        print self.ip
        if "back" in self.ip:
            rm.back()
        elif "yes" in self.ip:
            while self.count > 0:
                print "Riddle"
                self.answer = raw_input("> ")
                if self.answer == "answer":
                    print "You got that right!"
                    rm.enter()
                else:
                    print "Try again!"
                    self.count -= 1
            print "No choices left."
            quit()
        else:
            print "Invalid command."
```

When I first enter this room, it asks me a query where if I say "yes" it asks me the riddle. The answer is "answer" and entering that takes me to the next room. When I come back to this room it asks me riddle room query again, but this time if I enter "back" it says Invalid Command which is the `else` case. It skips over the first `if`. I added `print self.ip` to check if `self.ip` is changing to `"back"` and it is!

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: As well as printing the value of self.ip, also print the value of ("back" in self.ip).

Comment: I'm using 2.7 on Windows. @ebe

Comment: Did any of the below answers work for you?

Comment: @jarmod I tried that just now and it shows True, so it does recognize "back" in self.ip. The flow is wrong for some reason.

Comment: not yet! trying...

Answer (score 0):

That is caused because you have not defined the back command in your loop. This is how you should change your code:

```
class Riddle_Room(Room):
    def activate(self):
        global current_room
        print "Riddle room query"
        current_room = "riddle_room"
        self.ip = raw_input("> ")
        self.count = 3
        print self.ip
        while self.count > 0:
            if "back" in self.ip:
                rm.back()
            elif "yes" in self.ip:
                print "Riddle"
                self.answer = raw_input("> ")
                if self.answer == "answer":
                    print "You got that right!"
                    rm.enter()
                else:
                    print "Try again!"
                    self.count -= 1
            print "No choices left."
            quit()
            else:
                print "Invalid command."
```

Comment: Doesn't the `print(); quit()` need to be outside the loop? As it stands isn't it a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Do an exercise of working through your code in your mind.

When you enter "yes" the first time, you will enter the section of code under `elif "yes" in self.ip`.  In this section of code, you will be asked three times for the answer.  But this section of code contains no check for the word "back".  Therefore, you will be asked three times for the answer and the only acceptable response is "answer".

In other words, "back" is only recognized as a response to the prompt "Riddle room query" but not to the prompt "Riddle".

Comment: but "riddle room query" is exactly where i enter "back" as the problem happens only when I enter the room the second time and it asks me "riddle room query" again upon entering.

Comment: Here's the flow of what is happening: enter room>query>"yes">riddle>"answer">enters next room. Now after coming back to this room, enter room>query>"back">invalid command (???)

Comment: In your code as written you will only encounter Riddle room query once per invocation of `activate`.  Where are you calling `activate`?  Are you calling it recursively from inside `rm.enter()`?  Why do you believe you would execute the Riddle room query more than once?

Comment: `rm.enter()` is a function I defined to go to the next room. I call `activate` in that next room, which is another instance of class `Room`. It does show Riddle room query when `activate` is invoked again. `self.ip` is also changed to "back" during the second time. It just skips the first `if` for some reason. I think I should find someone IRL to help me with this, I'm stumped.